# Dynamically add <a> Tag in all Images<img> in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'd like to dynamically add  Tag in all Images in a specific div with a rel-Attribute.

e.g my Code in HTML

```
<div id="content">
  <img src="images/1.jpg"  alt="Pic One" />
  <img src="images/2.jpg"  alt="Pic Two" />
  (...)
</div>
```

After the JavaScript function, it should be like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <a href="images/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Pic One"/></a>
  <a href="images/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Pic One"/></a>
  (...)
</div>
```

Is there a suitable way to do this? Perhaps with regex?

Comment: there are many suitable ways to do this , but what u have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#content img').each(function(){
  $(this).wrap('<a href="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" rel="prettyPhoto"></a>');
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J88Jn/)**

Comment: +1 Didn't know `wrap` function in jQuery, seems useful!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript alone can do this.  First, select all the images inside the div:

```
var images=document.getElementById("content").querySelectorAll("img");
```

Then, you'll want to loop through each and edit it:

```
for (var I=0; I<images.length; I++){
    images[I].outerHTML="<a href='"+images[I].src+"' rel='prettyPhoto'>"+images[I].outerHTML+"</a>";
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#content > img").each(function(){
    $(this).wrap("<a>");
});
```